# Lightbox2-image gallery

Tags: html, lightbox2

I have a private (not public) website. In this website I want to use Lightbox2 (image gallery), but when I run lightbox2, the links of my home page and my background picture don't work.

There is a `style.css` in  my template, and there is also one in lightbox2. I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read how to ask; your question doesn't include enough information to be answerable.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see how to ask a good question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as your current question does not contain enough details to be answerable

Answer (score 0):

Simply load in your own stylesheet and the one lightbox uses in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css">
```

At the end of the page you must also load in the javascript that comes with lightbox:

```
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to set the right attribute for all your pictures:

```
<a href="./pic.jpeg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
        <img src="./pic.jpeg" style="width:100%">
</a>
```